# How do I create the dots on my custom carousel?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, carousel

I'm still beginner with `CSS` and `Javascript`. I tried to make a `carousel` using CSS and JavaScript.

I would like to know how do I create the logic for the dots on my custom carousel?

I created the buttons, and they are working to pass the slides. But can you tell me how do I create the dots?

This is my project into [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-thunder-edpx3?file=/src/index.js)

[image]

```js
export function usePosition(ref) {
  const [prevElement, setPrevElement] = React.useState(null);
  const [nextElement, setNextElement] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const element = ref.current;

    const update = () => {
      const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();

      const visibleElements = Array.from(element.children).filter((child) => {
        const childRect = child.getBoundingClientRect();

        return rect.left <= childRect.left && rect.right >= childRect.right;
      });

      if (visibleElements.length > 0) {
        setPrevElement(getPrevElement(visibleElements));
        setNextElement(getNextElement(visibleElements));
      }
    };

    update();
    element.addEventListener("scroll", update, { passive: true });

    return () => {
      element.removeEventListener("scroll", update, { passive: true });
    };
  }, [ref]);

  const scrollToElement = React.useCallback(
    (element) => {
      const currentNode = ref.current;

      if (!currentNode || !element) return;

      let newScrollPosition;

      newScrollPosition =
        element.offsetLeft +
        element.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2 -
        currentNode.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2;

      console.log("newScrollPosition: ", newScrollPosition);

      currentNode.scroll({
        left: newScrollPosition,
        behavior: "smooth"
      });
    },
    [ref]
  );

  const scrollRight = React.useCallback(() => scrollToElement(nextElement), [
    scrollToElement,
    nextElement
  ]);

  return {
    hasItemsOnLeft: prevElement !== null,
    hasItemsOnRight: nextElement !== null,
    scrollRight,
    scrollLeft
  };
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help!!

Answer (score -1):

below you will find my solution, I took your code from the sandbox and worked with it. I didn't understand if you wanted to show the dots, to scroll and sync the dots and click on the dots to change the image, so I did all of them .
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/test-1cyxl?file=/src/Carousel/Carousel.js)